# self.revealViewController is nil when a pass for another viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift

this is my code in the tableviewcontroller for calling revealviewcontroller

```
if self.revealViewController() != nil {
            menuBtn.target = self.revealViewController()
            menuBtn.action = "revealToggle:"
            self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
        }
```

and I have a popover and that popover contents a button that call back the tableviewcontroller, but when it come back, the revealViewController is nil.
Here is the code for go back

```
let dvc : ProductoTVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ProductoTVC") as! ProductoTVC
        self.presentViewController(dvc, animated:false, completion: nil)
```